# Creating deterministic one time passwords for every device

Tags: android, security, random, passwords

I'm looking to install an android app on a set of tablets for internal company use. These tablets will be used in the field and I want the password to expire after 30 days and switch to a pre-determined (but random seeming) password every 30 days. I'd like that password to be unique for every tablet/install of the app. I will be installing the apps myself on each tablet before distribution.

I looked at various OTP schemes but couldn't find one that would work without requiring to connect to a server. To be honest, I've never done anything like this before and was a bit overwhelmed.  Most of these tablets will not have access to internet while in the field and I'd like to be able to have users call in to get the next password after 30 days.

So ideally there's a pre-determined sequence of pseudo random numbers for each device, the user is given the password for this month and after 30 days, they have to call in to get the password for the current month for their specific tablet.

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I'll stream a couple of ideas I have about how you would achieve this.

My first thought when reading this was "You can do all of this through interacting with a Server, and frankly it would be easy with that support" until, of course, you noted that this wasn't possible.

I am making these suggestions under a few assumptions:

1. No one from your company is going to try to exploit the app in any way - like overbuffering or changing the apps language or utf settings etc etc. Also they won't try to look at any of the source files.
2. You will always get your hands on the devices before the people in your company use them.

Alright then, the handling of the 30-day predicament: The easiest way (though also most error prone way) would be to the get the systems current time (and date) when the user logs in, and set that  "day" as counter "30 or "0." This can be done with `Time now = new Time();
now.setToNow();` or `Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();`. Store this "day" in your own `SharedPreferences` or just the `DefaultSharedPreferences`. Every time the app starts check this day with your current day, and calculate how many days it's been. If the current amount of days is 30 or greater, reset the password.

^This was one of the most simple, and also very "error...full?" (Couldn't think of a good word) ways to solve this. Now on to the passwords:

I would recommend using UUID for the passwords. Although the identifiers made aren't "technically" unique, the chances of getting the same password twice are...well so close to zero in your case it's probably not going to happen.

Generate these and store, lets say 1000 different ones into a file onto each device (a simple text file with each password on a different line will work), and save a copy in your own records (Make sure you know which passwords go to which device).

Then when that calendar counter from earlier goes off, set the password for the app as the "next" password in the file, deleting previous one from the file. The company employee calls you with his app Id (Generate an app ID the user can see in each app. So the first person who gets his app has app #1, the second is app#2 etc. so that you know which password file you should be reading from) you can send him the new password.

These are two veeeeeerrrryyy simple ways to handle this, but they might be able to at least get you thinking. Hope I helped a bit.